# having an asp back button in popup window for displaying pdf

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, popupwindow

Am having a popup window for displaying pdf.. but i need to put an asp button in pop up window have tried the following code but could not find a solution.. can any one resolve this?

```
enter code here
    <asp Page attributes>
...............
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


<br />
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>   <asp:Button ID="dd"  runat="server" OnClick="Backonclick" Text="back"/>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

on page load event
dd.Visible = true;
         string path = Request.QueryString["val"].ToString();
        string extention = Path.GetExtension(path);
        int len = extention.Length - 1;
        string extwithoutdot = extention.Substring(1, len);

        if (extwithoutdot.Equals("JPG") || extwithoutdot.Equals("jpg") ||
            extwithoutdot.Equals("jpeg") || extwithoutdot.Equals("JPEG"))
        {
            extwithoutdot = "jpeg";
...........
```

Comment: How is the PDF included within this window?

Comment: path is obtained from parent window and its displayed in pop up using following code            'if (buffer != null)
        {
            if (filetype.Equals("PDF"))
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/" + extwithoutdot;
            }
            else
            {
                Response.ContentType = "image/" + extwithoutdot;
            }   
           
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);'

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're mixing two separate types of documents; a PDF is one type of download, whilst an HTML is another. A single download can't unfortunately be both, and you can't switch document types part-way through and expect the browser to handle it.

The simplest solution for what you're after is to combine the two on the client side. Load your pop-up as an HTML page (generated by ASP.NET if you wish) and include within that an `IFRAME` linking to your PDF generation script; something of the form:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a class='button' href="javascript:window.close()">Close</a>
        <iframe src="generatePdf.aspx" height="300" width="300" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's probably because I missed a quote character! Have edited to correct that.

Answer (score -1):

i have got solution

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

<iframe src="Copy (2) of DisplayPdf.aspx" width="1000" height="400">

</iframe>

<iframe src="Copy of DisplayPdf.aspx" width="100" height="200">

</iframe>
    </form>
```

Comment: You should explain how this answers the question. As I see it, it does not.